# How to fix this in error rails "warning: 299 Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, homebrew, searchkick

I have a Rails app that uses Searchkick and after updating my gems and yarn, I'm getting this Elasticsearch warning"

```
warning: 299 Elasticsearch-7.13.1-9a7758028e4ea59bcab41c12004603c5a7dd84a9 "Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security."
```

I tried following the instructions at the [webpage mentioned](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/security-minimal-setup.html), but I'm getting stuck at the `run the elasticsearch-setup-passwords utility` step. I can't find this script anywhere.

I'm currently on an M1 Mac, but running terminal with Rosetta, so homebrew was installed with Rosetta.

This is just for my development machine, so it doesn't seem like security is that important and previous versions of Elasticsearch installed with Homebrew did not display this warning.

Here's what I'm running now:

- ruby 3.0.0p0
- Rails 6.1.3.2
- Elasticsearch 7.10.2 (but for some reason this error references 7.13.1 ??) I installed it with homebrew using `brew install Elasticsearch` && `brew services start elasticsearch`)
- searchkick (4.5.0)

Is there a way to ignore this message? Or how do I fix this? It's so large in my console that I can't read my tests.

Comment: according to the tutorial, his script should be in `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords` have you checked there?

Comment: Yes, I don't have elasticsearch-setup-passwords in this directory. Followed the path here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html) and there is no "elasticsearch-setup-passwords" script.

Comment: Ok the reason `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords` wasn't available is I ran `brew install elasticsearch` (per the Searchkick gem docs), when I should have run `brew install elasticsearch-full` to install `elasticsearch-full`. More on that here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This warning is shown because you have the security plugin enabled but not configurated.

If you don't want security you can disable xpack and it should do the trick

simply add this line in your configuration `elasticsearch.yml`  :

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

UPDATE: to check the location of the `elasticsearch.yml` file in your Mac, run `brew info elasticsearch` and it will be located inside the config folder displayed.

Comment: This is what I thought would work and I had already tried this to no avail. I did this in  the elasticsearch.yml file at /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch per this doc -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html

Comment: Update: This worked to fix it after I installed `elasticsearch-full` with homebrew instead of `elasticsearch`. First I ran `brew install elasticsearch-full`, then added the `xpack.security.enabled: false` line to `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, then ran `brew services restart elasticsearch-full`.

Comment: For my M1 Mac the folder was in a slightly different location `opt/homebrew/etc/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 15):

Adding to @luc-e answer. If you have Elastic installed as Docker container, then you should do the following:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
echo "xpack.security.enabled: false" >> elasticsearch.yml
```

and restart your container

Answer (score 7):

For development with docker where you don't care about security, you can disable this warning via environment variables:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: blacktop/elasticsearch:7.17
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: I prefer compose to regular docker file, thank you